# How do I know what version of the AWS PHP SDK I have?

Tags: aws-php-sdk

We have updated our web site to PHP 8.2 and now the AWS SDK is throwing errors. I am not sure where to look in the files to figure out what version of the SDK I have installed. And it is very unclear which PHP version I can use with the SDK - does the most recent version work in PHP 8.2 at all?

My development site which is still on PHP 7.4 works but on PHP 8.2 I get

Error thrown
Unknown named parameter $instance

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY');

$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'version'     => 'latest',
'region'      => 'us-east-1',
'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

and I have opened several of the SDK files to try to find a version or something.

And I don't know if I update to the latest SDK - will it work with 8.2?

Comment: I open /vendor/Aws/Sdk.php and there is a line that says this - but the number is higher than the current SDK version on git - so I am confused
class Sdk
{
    const VERSION = '3.69.3';

Answer (score 2):

assuming you installed with composer use this

```
composer show aws/aws-sdk-php
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest aws/aws-sdk-php (3.278.1) works well with php 8.2. You will maybe have to update your code according to the latest php and sdk modifications.